# How to detect if dates are consecutive in Python?

Tags: python, date, date-range

I have an access table with a 'Date' field. it has random dates for each record. I've built a script to append all the records into a list and then set the list to filter out only the unique values:

```
dateList = []
# cursor search through each record and append all records in the date 
# field to a python list
for row in rows:
   dateList.append(row.getValue("DATE_OBSERVATION").strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))

# Filter unique values to a set
newList = list(set(dateList))
```

This returns (on my test table):

['07-06-2010', '06-24-2010', '07-05-2010', '06-25-2010']

Now that I have the unique values for the "DATE_OBSERVATION" field, I want to detect if:

- the dates are single (i.e. only one unique date is returned because that is the date in every record)
- if the dates are a range of dates (i.e. all of the dates fall into a consecutive range)
- if the dates are multiple dates, but are not in a range of consecutive dates

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!
Mike

Comment: Short lazy reply: Convert them into datetime objects, sort them then use the `pairwise` recipe from the `itertools` doc page to compare all dates against the next one in the list to see if it's a range; for single dates, take the date of the first and check that all the rest are within the same calendar day; if both of those fail they're disparate dates.

Comment: if you don't select other values, use `select distinct date_observation from mytable order by date_observation desc` and don't convert dates to strings..

Comment: @deathApril: why descending order?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian uh,, no reason - i saw '07-06-2010', '06-24-2010' in the question and skipped the rest of the examples i guess..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rather than rolling your own `consecutive` function you can simply convert date objects to integers using the `.toordinal()` method of datetime objects. The difference between the maximum and minimum value of the set of ordinal dates is one more than the length of the set:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_strs = ['07-06-2010', '06-24-2010', '07-05-2010', '06-25-2010']
# date_strs = ['02-29-2012', '02-28-2012', '03-01-2012']
# date_strs = ['01-01-2000']
dates = [datetime.strptime(d, "%m-%d-%Y") for d in date_strs]

date_ints = set([d.toordinal() for d in dates])

if len(date_ints) == 1:
    print "unique"
elif max(date_ints) - min(date_ints) == len(date_ints) - 1:
    print "consecutive"
else:
    print "not consecutive"
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This worked well with my script! I appreciate your response.

Comment: @Michael Dillon: `select distinct ..` as in @deathApril's comment is even better.

Comment: if we consider ['01-01-2000', '01-01-2000', '01-02-2000'] to be not consecutive, using this code will say the dates are consecutive, how might you modified your code to consider this requirement? I don't know how sets work yet.

Comment: @lessthanl0l: sets remove duplicates. If you want to consider a list with duplicates as non-consecutive you could test to see whether the length of your list of dates is greater than the length of the set of dates.

Answer (score 1):

Another version using the same logic as in my other answer.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Definition 1: 1/1/14, 1/2/14, 1/2/14, 1/3/14 is consider consecutive
# Definition 2: 1/1/14, 1/2/14, 1/2/14, 1/3/14 is consider not consecutive

# datelist = [date(2014, 1, 1), date(2014, 1, 3),
#             date(2013, 12, 31), date(2013, 12, 30)]

# datelist = [date(2014, 2, 19), date(2014, 2, 19), date(2014, 2, 20),
#             date(2014, 2, 21), date(2014, 2, 22)]

datelist = [date(2014, 2, 19), date(2014, 2, 21),
            date(2014, 2, 22), date(2014, 2, 20)]

datelist.sort()

previousdate = datelist[0]

for i in range(1, len(datelist)):
    #if (datelist[i] - previousdate).days == 1 or (datelist[i] - previousdate).days == 0:  # for Definition 1
    if (datelist[i] - previousdate).days == 1:    # for Definition 2
        previousdate = datelist[i]
    else:
        previousdate = previousdate + timedelta(days=-1)

if datelist[-1] == previousdate:
    print "dates are consecutive"
else:
    print "dates are not consecutive"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your database to select unique dates in the ascending order:

- if the query returns a single date it is your first case
- otherwise find out whether the dates are consecutive:

  ```
  import datetime

  def consecutive(a, b, step=datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
      return (a + step) == b
  ```

Code layout:

```
dates = <query database>
if all(consecutive(dates[i], dates[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(dates) - 1)):
   if len(dates) == 1: # unique
      # 1st case: all records have the same date
   else:
      # the dates are a range of dates
else:
   # non-consecutive dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version using the reduce() function.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


def checked(d1, d2):
    """
    We assume the date list is sorted.
    If d2 & d1 are different by 1, everything up to d2 is consecutive, so d2
    can advance to the next reduction.
    If d2 & d1 are not different by 1, returning d1 - 1 for the next reduction
    will guarantee the result produced by reduce() to be something other than
    the last date in the sorted date list.

    Definition 1: 1/1/14, 1/2/14, 1/2/14, 1/3/14 is consider consecutive
    Definition 2: 1/1/14, 1/2/14, 1/2/14, 1/3/14 is consider not consecutive

    """
    #if (d2 - d1).days == 1 or (d2 - d1).days == 0:  # for Definition 1
    if (d2 - d1).days == 1:                          # for Definition 2
        return d2
    else:
        return d1 + timedelta(days=-1)

# datelist = [date(2014, 1, 1), date(2014, 1, 3),
#             date(2013, 12, 31), date(2013, 12, 30)]

# datelist = [date(2014, 2, 19), date(2014, 2, 19), date(2014, 2, 20),
#             date(2014, 2, 21), date(2014, 2, 22)]

datelist = [date(2014, 2, 19), date(2014, 2, 21),
            date(2014, 2, 22), date(2014, 2, 20)]

datelist.sort()

if datelist[-1] == reduce(checked, datelist):
    print "dates are consecutive"
else:
    print "dates are not consecutive"
```