# Split a list of dates into subsets of consecutive dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, python-datetime

I've got an array of dates that can contain multiple date ranges in it.

```
dates = [
 '2020-01-01',
 '2020-01-02',
 '2020-01-03',
 '2020-01-06',
 '2020-01-07',
 '2020-01-08'
]
```

In this example, the list contains 2 separate consecutive date ranges (2020-01-01 to 2020-01-03 & 2020-01-06 to 2020-01-08)

I'm attempting to figure out how I would loop through this list and find all the consecutive date ranges.

One of the articles I'm looking at ([How to detect if dates are consecutive in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589523/how-to-detect-if-dates-are-consecutive-in-python)) seems to have a good approach, however, I'm struggling to implement this logic in my use case.

Comment: Please show us your attempt :)

Comment: could you share the code you have written so far?

Comment: I've placed my solution below, sometimes you need to type out the issue for things to click :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More itertools has a function called [`consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=unique#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) that does this for you:

Or you can view the source code and copy it's approach:

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def consecutive_groups(iterable, ordering=lambda x: x):
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(iterable), key=lambda x: x[0] - ordering(x[1])):
        yield map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

Then to use the function:

```
for g in consecutive_groups(dates, lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal()):
    print(list(g))
```

Or *(more appropriately)* using a function instead of lambda:

```
def to_date(date):
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal()

for g in consecutive_groups(dates, to_date):
    print(list(g))
```

---

```
['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03']
['2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08']
```

Comment: Excellent solution.  Maybe you could explain the key concept on which it is based, since it looks a bit cryptic: i.e. enumerate provides a continuous sequence. The difference of each date with it remains constant until there is a gap. That change triggers the grouping. Simple and efficient,  very elegant

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution, more readable. And learned about more-itertools :) thank you @jab

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that single-date "ranges" are still represented by 2 dates:

```
def makedate(s):
    return datetime.strptime( s, "%Y-%m-%d" )
def splitIntoRanges( dates ):
    ranges = []
    start_s = last_s = dates[0]
    last = makedate(start_s)
    for curr_s in dates[1:]:
        curr = makedate(curr_s)
        if (curr - last).days > 1:
            ranges.append((start_s,last_s))
            start_s = curr_s
        last_s = curr_s
        last = curr
    return ranges + [(start_s,last_s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar, though definitely not quite as elegant approach as @Scott:

```
ranges = []

dates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') for date in dates]
start = dates[0]

for i in range(1, len(dates)):
    if (dates[i] - dates[i-1]).days == 1 and i==len(dates)-1:
        end = dates[i]
        ranges.append(f'{start} to {end}')
        start = dates[i]
    elif (dates[i] - dates[i - 1]).days > 1:
        end = dates[i - 1]
        ranges.append(f'{start} to {end}')
        start = dates[i]
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the key to my solution in a second post and pieced it together.

There are two parts to my issue:

1. How do I represent a list of dates in an effective manner

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9589929/2150673

```
pto = [
    '2020-01-03',
    '2020-01-08',
    '2020-01-02',
    '2020-01-07',
    '2020-01-01',
    '2020-01-06'
]

ordinal_dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal() for i in pto]
```

2. Once you have a list of dates in integer representation, you can simply look for consecutive integers and get the upper and lower bounds of each range, and then convert back to yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48106843

```
def ranges(nums):
    nums = sorted(set(nums))
    gaps = [[s, e] for s, e in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if s+1 < e]
    edges = iter(nums[:1] + sum(gaps, []) + nums[-1:])
    return list(zip(edges, edges))
```

My complete function:

```
def get_date_ranges(pto_list: list) -> list:
    pto_dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal() for i in pto_list]
    nums = sorted(set(pto_dates))
    gaps = [[s, e] for s, e in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if s + 1 < e]
    edges = iter(nums[:1] + sum(gaps, []) + nums[-1:])
    ordinal_ranges = list(zip(edges, edges))
    date_bounds = []
    for start, end in ordinal_ranges:
        date_bounds.append((
            datetime.datetime.fromordinal(start).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            datetime.datetime.fromordinal(end).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        ))
    return date_bounds
```

Comment: While this does answer my question I am interested in finding optimization for this. Ashamed to say, I don't fully understand every part of this function and need to spend some time with these basic python functions.

Comment: @Jab 's solution is the one and only worth picking.  Elegant and efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the consecutive date ranges and append them to a list of list and access your ranges based on the index but I prefer using keys within a dictionary for readability.

Here is how: (note: please read comments)

```
dates = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d") for d in dates] # new datetime parsed from a string
date_ints = [d.toordinal() for d in dates]  # toordinal() returns the day count from the date 01/01/01 in integers
ranges = {}; arange = []; prev=0; index=0; j=1
for i in date_ints: # iterate through date integers
    if i+1 == date_ints[index] + 1 and i - 1 == prev: # check and compare if integers are in sequence
        arange.append(dates[index].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    elif prev == 0: # append first date to 'arange' list since 'prev' has not been updated
        arange.append(dates[index].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    else:
        ranges.update({f'Range{j}': tuple(arange)}) # integer are no longer in sequence, update dictionary with new range  
        arange = []; j += 1                                   # clear 'arange' and start appending to new range  
        arange.append(dates[index].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    index += 1; prev = i
ranges.update({f'Range{j}': tuple(arange)})
print(ranges)  
print(ranges['Range1'])  # access a range based on the associated key
print(ranges['Range2'])
```

outputs:

```
{'Range1': ('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03'), 'Range2': ('2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08')}
('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03')
('2020-01-06', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08')
```